# Spring classes not found

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I am trying to follow this wikibook:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Spring_framework

[image: Deprecated errors]

How to resolve the errors?

EDIT:

I added the jar files to the class path:
The imports still don't work. The number of errors did not go down. So this means that deprecation is the only issue.

[image: second screenshot]

Comment: Have you added the spring libraries to your classpath?

Comment: I used eclipse plugin for Spring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see on the screenshot you are missing the two jars that you need - `spring-core` and `spring-beans` (`org.springframework.core/beans`) - you have only their `-sources` jars, which do not contain compiled classes.

As for the deprecation - it only shows warnings. But consult the documentation of the deprecated class to see what's its replacement.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the appropriate libraries to the *classpath*. For more information, see [How to Add JARs to Project Build Paths in Eclipse (Java)](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29). Also, to "get around" deprecation, follow the proposed alternate solutions, which are typically suggested in the [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M2/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/XmlBeanFactory.html).

Comment: he has added some jars in the classpath (he added screenshot), but the important ones are missing. But +1 for telling him how to add them in the first place

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [javadocs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M2/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/XmlBeanFactory.html).

> Deprecated. as of Spring 3.1 in favor of DefaultListableBeanFactory and XmlBeanDefinitionReader

Comment: So if I replace XMLBeanFactory with DefaultListableBeanFactory, it should work out?

Comment: but it won't, because he doesn't have the jars ;)